# Eclipse Galileo Repository Installation error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried install new software on eclipse from  "Web, XML, and Java EE Development" with this path

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo
```

I take this error while my proccess

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.1.1.v200908120400-7R77FStEVw2z07WtDz-OZrhL5C-3 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908120400-7R77FStEVw2z07WtDz-OZrhL5C-3)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.0.3.R36x_v20110111 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.0.3.R36x_v20110111)
    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.0.2.R36x_v20100804 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.0.2.R36x_v20100804)

    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.1.1.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.1.1.dist)
    Equinox Provisioning Core 1.0.100.v20090520-1905 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 1.0.100.v20090520-1905)
    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.0.0.v20100510 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.0.0.v20100510)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core [2.1.1.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.dist-8291FXcFLhV8CJ871602A41]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.1.2.dist-6-Bk8lt6MLqLsEf6-RFpFIpRdhQG]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery 1.0.1.v20100210
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core [1.0.100,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WST Server UI 3.1.1.v20090727b-7B3DPAtJZRZxULQRALIM4256 (org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v20090727b-7B3DPAtJZRZxULQRALIM4256)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery [1.0.1.v20100210]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.1.1.v200908120400-7R77FStEVw2z07WtDz-OZrhL5C-3 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908120400-7R77FStEVw2z07WtDz-OZrhL5C-3)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature.feature.group [3.1.1.v20090727b-7B3DPAtJZRZxULQRALIM4256]    Equinox Provisioning Core 1.0.101.R35x_v20090819 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 1.0.101.R35x_v20090819)
```

What can I do for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are using Eclipse Indigo and trying to install software from previous version of Eclipse Galileo. The releases of eclipse differs by core plug-ins (also called bundles). The installation of ""Web, XML, and Java EE Development" software requires Galileo core bundles that you don't have. So the Eclipse tries to download and install them for you. The problem is that now you have two different versions of the core plug-ins and Eclipse will not know to link the right one.
the solution is to use link to Indigo version of Eclipse:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo